# Is it possible to change the order of items in Parcellite's persistent clipboard?

Tags: clipboard, parcellite

Is it possible to organize the items on Parcellite's persistent clipboard? I tried moving items from the persistent clipboard back to the normal clipboard, and then back to the persistent clipboard, in hopes that it would add them to the persistent clipboard in the same order in which I moved them back. However, it doesn't seem to work that way. It just puts them back in the original order.